# Using multiple lasers with laser_scan_matcher

Tags: ros, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Has anyone tried using laser_scan_matcher with multiple laser sensors? There is nothing about it in the documentation, but that hasn't been updated since Fuerte. I am using laser_scan_matcher for the odom transform of an omnidirectional robot and I have 2 LRFs, one facing forward and one facing rearward. I'm wondering if having laser_scan_matcher subscribe to the scan topic, where I am publishing the data from both lasers, would work or if that will cause a problem with it trying to match scans that are completely different.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207695/using-multiple-lasers-with-laser_scan_matcher/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out. After looking through the node's code I found that it saves the frame id of the first scan it gets, then for subsequent scans it ignores those that don't have the same frame id. So it doesn't use multiple sensors, but you can publish the data from multiple sensors to the /scan topic without having to worry about laser_scan_matcher throwing a fit.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2015-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0